# libXss.so.1 no such file or directory

Tags: linux, fedora

I am trying to install Jetbrains toolbox on my new Fedora 27 installation. However, everytime I try to run the install, the command line says the following:

```
> share/jetbrains-toolbox/jetbrains-toolbox: error while loading shared
> libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file
> or directory
```

I tried to run this to solve it, however it still doesn't work:

```
sudo dnf install libXss.so.1
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

On Fedora 27 this dependency is provided by installing the libXss runtime library:

`sudo dnf install libXScrnSaver`

An AppImage should provide it's dependencies so this is just a workaround.

Comment: Note that `sudo dnf install /usr/lib64/libXss.so.1` would have worked, too.